# Why this lookup names and value doesn't work?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to print names and value from classified images with this code

```
//**Set center **//
Map.setCenter(103.667, 11.5019, 9);

//**Import Copernicus Global Landcover dataset
var dataset = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
              .clip (roi);
              
//**Selection attribute value
var classified = dataset.select(['discrete_classification']);

//**Visualize land cover map on canvas
Map.addLayer(classified, {}, "Land Cover Combodja");

//**grouping the images
var landcover_class = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classified);
print (landcover_class)

//**Calculation area
var reduction_results = landcover_class.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1,
    groupName: 'Landcover ID',
  }),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 100,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
print('reduction_results', reduction_results);
var roi_stats = ee.List(reduction_results.get('groups'));
print('roi_stats', roi_stats)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var roi_stats = ee.List(reduction_results.get('groups'));
// Create a dictionary for looking up names of transition classes.
var lookup_names = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
    ee.List(gsw.get('classification_values')).map(ee.String),
    gsw.get('classification_names')
);
print (lookup_names)
// Create a dictionary for looking up colors of transition classes.
var lookup_palette = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
    ee.List(gsw.get('transition_class_values')).map(ee.String),
    gsw.get('transition_class_palette')
);
print (lookup_palette)
```

however, these code doesnt work and something appears in console "Dictionary (Error)
List.map: Parameter 'list' is required.
"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have simultaneously class names and sums in your final result, you have to map **roi_stats** with a function able to retrieve class names from corresponding list by using indices obtained from values class list. Following script can do that where I created an arbitrary **roi** area (you don't provide one) that encloses your point (103.667, 11.5019).

```
//**Set center **//
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([103.667, 11.5019]);

var roi =ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[103.5626298828125, 11.418453478561592],
          [103.677986328125, 11.375374688788868],
          [103.89496630859375, 11.46690929767244],
          [103.83454150390625, 11.590702996961742],
          [103.68897265625, 11.58801241064796],
          [103.6505205078125, 11.628368481791046],
          [103.55439013671875, 11.628368481791046],
          [103.51319140625, 11.534195251171665]]]);

Map.setCenter(103.667, 11.5019, 9);
//Map.addLayer(pt);


//**Import Copernicus Global Landcover dataset
var dataset = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
              .clip (roi);

print(dataset.propertyNames());

var ds_names = dataset.get('discrete_classification_class_names');
print("class names", ds_names);


var ds_value = dataset.get('discrete_classification_class_values');
print("class values", ds_value);

var ds_palette = dataset.get('discrete_classification_class_palette');
print("palette names", ds_palette);

//**Selection attribute value
var classified = dataset.select(['discrete_classification']);

//**Visualize land cover map on canvas
Map.addLayer(classified, {}, "Land Cover Combodja");

//**grouping the images
var landcover_class = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(classified);

print (landcover_class);

//**Calculation area
var reduction_results = landcover_class.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1,
    groupName: 'Landcover ID',
  }),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 100,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});

print('reduction_results', reduction_results);

var roi_stats = ee.List(reduction_results.get('groups'));

print('roi_stats', roi_stats);

var pairNameSum = roi_stats.map(function (ele) {
  
  var val = ee.Dictionary(ele).get('Landcover ID');
  var sum = ee.Dictionary(ele).get('sum');
    
  var idx = ee.List(ds_value).indexOf(ee.Number(val));
  
  return [ee.List(ds_names).get(idx), sum];
  
});


print('roi_stats with class names', pairNameSum);
```

After running above script in GEE code editor, I got result of following image. There are printed class names paired with respective sums.

[image]